# Swift + iOS: How to call closure from within async call?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a web view inside of my app. I'm currently looking at each request and seeing if they are a youtube video before allowing / canceling the request:

```
extension WebBrowserViewController: WKNavigationDelegate {
  func webView(webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyForNavigationAction navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    if (urlVideoType(webView.URL!) != VideoUrl.Unknown && urlVideoType(webView.URL!) != VideoUrl.Youtube) {
      ...
    } else if urlVideoType(webView.URL!) == VideoUrl.Youtube {
      // the success and failure part don't work
      presentYoutubeVideoIfAvailable(webView.URL!, success: decisionHandler(.Cancel), failure: decisionHandler(.Allow)) <-------------------
    } else {
      decisionHandler(.Allow)
    }
  }
}
```

My `presentYoutubeVideoIfAvailable` method uses this youtube url parser pod: https://github.com/movielala/YoutubeSourceParserKit

However, that makes an async call and I don't know how to make it call the success and failure methods in my method:

```
  func presentYoutubeVideoIfAvailable(url: NSURL, success: (), failure: ()) {
    Youtube.h264videosWithYoutubeURL(url) {  [unowned self] (videoInfo, _) -> Void in
      switch videoInfo?["url"] as? String {
      case .Some(let videoUrlString):
        VideoStore.addVideo(url.absoluteString, title: videoInfo?["title"] as? String ?? "Unknown")
        success
        self.presentVideo(NSURL(string: videoUrlString)!)
      case .None:
        print("herereee") // gets printed, so I know it's here
        failure // doesn't do anything. it should be allowing the request but it isn't <-----------------------------------
        self.showError(.YoutubeParsingFail)
      }
    }
  }
```

I want it so that if the youtube pod returns a url, it should cancel the web view request, and if it fails I want it to continue with the request. How would I do this?

Comment: Needs to be `success()` and `failure()` you're not actually calling the closures.

Answer (score 1):

The reason nothing is happening here is that you're not calling the closures. Closures should be called like any other function in swift, like so:

`success()`
`failure()`